# SquareUp payment gateway issue while integration Reader for iPad

Tags: payment-gateway, square-connect

Integrating Square-Up Reader for iPad. According to their document mentioned on

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/readersdk/setup-ios

**Prerequisites**

To build with Reader SDK, the following must be true:

You are using Xcode 9.1+
You are using an iOS Base SDK of 11.1 or newer.
The **deployment target for your app is iOS 11.0 or newer**

But **iPad latest ios version is 9.3.5**

**Problem I am facing is:**

Whenever I build project according to the flow mentioned in there document, every time it through error

```
.../SquareReaderSDK.framework/SquareReaderSDK, missing required architecture armv7 in file ..../SquareReaderSDK.framework/SquareReaderSDK (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SQRDReaderSDK", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Order_Detail_VC.o
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone please guide how to resolve this issue.
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Reader SDK requires at least iOS 11. Newer iPads (after 4th generation) have the ability to upgrade to the latest iOS versions (currently 12.1 I believe). If your iPad is a 4th generation or older, it will not be able to run Reader SDK applications.

Note that it is possible to get it to run on iOS 10, which a 4th generation iPad would be able to handle, however there's extra settings you need to configure:

> If you need to support iOS 10, you must restrict your supported architectures to arm64 only:
>
> 1. Open the Build Settings tab for your target in Xcode.
> 2. Set the Architectures and Valid Architectures values to arm64.
> 3. Open your Info.plist file in Xcode.
> 4. Set UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to arm64.
>
> Your app will not be able to run on a device that does not support 64-bit code.

More information can be found here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/readersdk/setup-ios